# Creating Data Table of Regression Coefficients

Tags: r, datatable, regression, na, coefficients

I have a model with the following regression coefficient values:

```
           (Intercept)                 radius              perimeter            compactness          concavepoints 
         -2.3003926746           0.0743984303          -0.0111031732          -2.5826629017           5.3127565914 
         radius.stderr      smoothness.stderr     compactness.stderr       concavity.stderr           radius.worst 
          0.4256225882          16.9805981122          -3.8819567231           0.9488969352           0.1408605366 
         texture.worst             area.worst        concavity.worst         symmetry.worst fractaldimension.worst 
          0.0105317616          -0.0009867991           0.3504860653           0.8536208289           4.7503948408
```

I want to make a data table with the variable names in one column, and the corresponding regression coefficient values in the other column.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
var_names = coef(summary(model_B))[, 0]
coef_vals = coef(summary(model_B))[, 1]
data.table(Variables=c(var_names), RegressionCoefficients = c(coef_values))
```

But I get the following output with the 'Variables' column all NA:

```
Variables RegressionCoefficients
<dbl> <dbl>
NA  -2.3003926746           
NA  0.0743984303            
NA  -0.0111031732           
NA  -2.5826629017           
NA  5.3127565914            
NA  0.4256225882            
NA  16.9805981122           
NA  -3.8819567231           
NA  0.9488969352            
NA  0.1408605366
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use names to access the names of the coefficients.

```
var_names=names(coef(model_B))
coef_vals=coef(model_B)
data.table(Variables=var_names, RegressionCoefficients=coef_vals)

     Variables RegressionCoefficients
1: (Intercept)           2.984208e-16
2:      radius           1.000000e+00
3:   perimeter           1.000000e+00
```

Comment: thanks so much! just to add on, is there a way to sort the variables in decreasing order of the absolute value of their regression coefficients?

Comment: nevermind! I got it with the code: 


`DT = data.table(Variables=var_names, RegressionCoefficients=coef_vals)`


`DT[order(-abs(RegressionCoefficients))]`